# How to get object-fit:cover working on Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css

I made the total noob mistake of not checking my site progress on IE until it was completely done and now I'm in a little bit of a pickle.

I am using a hero and slideshow on my site, both of which have an overlay, and within the overlay, an image with the `object-fit: cover` property and the `object-position: top`. When viewing on IE, there is no image that appears at all. I looked around at a few possible solutions but they don't seem to work for this situation with the overlay.

[Here](https://codepen.io/jeremylucas/pen/KKKrvWX) is my CodePen. Of course, it works on here too , but on IE it does not work.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tn2ve.jpg) is what I see on IE

Are there any suggested workarounds? 
Thank you in advance for your help. Here is the code snippet:

```css
.hero {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
}
.hero .overlay {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.overlay img {
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: top;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero">
  <div class="overlay">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/500" alt="placeholder image">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This might help you out https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_hero_image.asp

Comment: thanks, this looks like a good start. I have been using the same css properties and changing the hero's (I have many pages that all have the hero section). Is this possible to do that in a way so each page has its own used image?

Comment: I changed things up and put the individual div tags to have the style:  , so in my case `<div class="hero" style="background-image: url('image here');" >` Thank you for your help with this, that solved the problem